# Callback for Google Sign in for macOS app

Tags: swift, swiftui, google-signin

I'm very new to SwiftUI and trying to play around with creating login screens. I managed to get the SignIn with Apple working but struggle a bit with SignIn with Google.

```
struct LoginViewController: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var loginViewModel : LoginViewModel
    let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration(clientID: "123456789-somerandomaplhanumericgru0008u.apps.googleusercontent.com")
    
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
      // Register for GetURL events.
      let appleEventManager = NSAppleEventManager.shared()
      appleEventManager.setEventHandler(
        self,
        andSelector: "handleGetURLEvent:replyEvent:",
        forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass),
        andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL)
      )
    }
    
    func handleGetURLEvent(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor?, replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor?) {
        if let urlString =
          event?.paramDescriptor(forKeyword: AEKeyword(keyDirectObject))?.stringValue{
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
            // GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
        }
    }
    
    func handleSignInButton() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig,
                                        presenting: self) { user, error in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let user = user else { return }

            let emailAddress = user.profile?.email

            let fullName = user.profile?.name
            let givenName = user.profile?.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile?.familyName

            let profilePicUrl = user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 320)
        }
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn,
                                  onRequest: loginViewModel.configure,
                                  onCompletion: loginViewModel.handle
            )
            .padding()
            
            GoogleSignInButton(action: handleSignInButton)
            .padding(.horizontal, 50)

        }
        
    
    }
    
}
```

The line:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig,
                                        presenting: self)
```

has the errors:

1. Cannot convert value of type 'GIDConfiguration' to expected argument type 'NSWindow'
2. Cannot convert value of type 'LoginViewController' to expected argument type 'String?'
3. Extra trailing closure passed in call

The references that I used to get to this point:

1. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/people
2. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in
3. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDSignIn

How do I resolve the three errors?

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://serg-ios.github.io/2021-03-10-my-vocabulary-google-signin/) . presenting parameter need a UIViewController and meant to be use with UIKit.

Comment: @PtitXav, UIKit is for iOS. I'm developing an macOS app.

Comment: i think on macOS it is meant for AppKit (NSWindow is AppKit) which is macOS equivalent of UIKit

Comment: Then how do I solve the above problem?

Comment: The link I gave you has a method to resolve your problem. BTW, your 2nd link should help you if you use SwiftUI parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248736/discussion-between-newkid-and-ptit-xav).